# Differentiating Lebesgue Integral - Application in Economics

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am currently reading up on measure theory and Lebesgue integration in order to gain a somewhat more nuanced understanding of a few "aggregation-adjacent" results in economics.

The context of my question essentially is that we have a continuum of agents collected in a set $H$ with Lebesgue measure 1.

Each of these agents $i\in H$ faces an individual price $p_i$ such that we basically have a function $p:H\to\mathbb{R}$. Agent $i$ also consumes a quantity given by $x:H\to\mathbb{R}$ and written as $x_i$.

Clearly the cost of consumption for each agent is given by $p_i\,x_i$ which yields an aggregate (and by the measure unity assumption average) cost of
$$\int_Hp_i\,x_i\,di.$$

So far, perfectly reasonable.

At this point a variety of textbooks just states - in a very cavalier way - that
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\,x_k}\int_Hp_i\,x_i\,di=p_k.$$

Why is that true?

I suppose that, provided $H$ was countable, we would think about the integral as a sum. And clearly,
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\,x_k}\sum_{i\in H}p_i\,x_i=p_k$$

However, $H$ is a continuum and we integrate w.r.t. to the usual Lebesgue measure.

I'd very much appreciate is someone could give me a rigorous argument for why the above is true and perhaps also an intuition for how I should think about this. After all, we are not differentiating w.r.t. a parameter such that we'd need some sort of Dominated Convergence Theorem type of argument, we are not differentiating in a Radon-Nikodym way. We are essentially differentiating the integral of a function $i\mapsto p_ix_i$ over $H$  with respect to a "component"  of this function evaluated at a specific point in the domain of this function, i.e. $x(k)$. Not quite sure how to make sense of this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $di$ mean?

Comment: That is the notation usually found in textbooks - without any sort of explanation. I took it to mean that the Lebesgue integral is w.r.t. Lebesgue measure in the sense that we have $\int_Hp(i)\,x(i)\,\lambda(\,di\,)$.

Comment: The notation is opaque to me. As far as I can understand, the first integral is a constant, it is not clear how it can depend on some $x_k$ any more that $\int x dx$ depends on some $x$.

Comment: I suppose that is exactly what I am struggling with. Translated into the realm of Rieman-Integration, the above would be essentially like asking to differentiate $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,dx$ with respect to $g(c)$ for some $c\in[\,a,b\,]$ which would not be obvious to me at all. Textbooks, however, treat this as if it was obvious...

Comment: Yes, certainly not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider taking the directional derivative in the direction of the $\delta_k$ function:

$$
\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{F(x+\tau \delta_k )-F(x)}{\tau} =\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\int_0^1 p_i (x_i+\tau \delta_k)d_i - \int_0^1 p_i x_i d_i}{\tau} = \lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\int_0^1 \tau p_i \delta_k di}{\tau} = \int_0^1 \delta_k p_i d_i = p_k.
$$

I find it to be true that economists almost always mean some kind of directional derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As a non-mathematician, may I briefly see whether I understood correctly? $\delta_k$ is the Dirac delta function, and we consider $i\mapsto x(i)+\tau\delta_k(i)$. Then, heuristically, we have that since $\int\delta_k\,di=1$ and $\delta_k=0$ for all $i\neq k$, it follows that $\int\,\delta_kp_i\,di=p_k$?

Comment: Yes.  It is a generalized function, so it might not be exactly what you want, but it makes some sense of the notation at least.  In the Lebesgue sense, changing a function on a set of measure zero should not change the value of the integral, since it is almost everywhere equal to the original function.  But if you use the directional derivative to sneak the delta function in, you can get the result in the book.

Comment: Alright, makes sense to me. After perusing the Wikipedia article on the Dirac Delta function, my only issue would be that the last integral in your sequence of equalities essentially is an integral with respect to the delta measure. The function $\delta_k$ does not actually exist as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of Lebesgue measure w.r.t. Delta measure - even though it seems customary to write it as an abuse of notation. My question would be how we work with this (non-existent) function in the directional derivative? I'm not sure, whether this question borders on the philosophical...